# Properly Escape $ in a nested remote command

Tags: bash, variables, ssh

I would like to execute a command on a remote host from another remote host.

```
HOST1=host1.domain.tld
HOST2=host2.domain.tld
```

`HOST1` is used to connect to `HOST2` and the command executes on `HOST2`.  The remote command depends a variable that is calculated on `HOST2`.

```
ssh -A $HOST1 -C "x=wrong; ssh -A $HOST2 -C "x=right; echo \$x""
```

Strangely, the above returns `$x` while the next command returns `wrong` instead of an empty line.

```
ssh -A $HOST1 -C "x=wrong; ssh -A $HOST2 -C "echo \$x""
```

Question 1: Why is the first command giving me `$x`?
Question 2: Keeping the double quotes, how do I have it print `right`?

Comment: All your `ssh` commands currently connect to `$HOST1`; which ones are supposed to be `$HOST2`?

Comment: You can/should tell ssh to do the work of using a bounce host for you. There's no need to do it manually yourself.

Answer (score 0):

## Section 1: Literal Answers

...to the question precisely as-asked.

#### Why is the first command giving me `$x`?

Keep in mind that this command is executed multiple times, and is thus transformed by multiple shells. That transformation looks something like the following (assuming `HOST1` of 1.1.1.1 and `HOST2` of 2.2.2.2):

```
ssh -A 1.1.1.1 -C "x=wrong; ssh -A 2.2.2.2. -C "x=right; echo \$x""
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^^
```

...note the arrows? Those are showing where your quoted regions begin and end: Your quote just before `x=right` is ending your quote that started before `x=wrong`!

Thus, this tokenizes to two separate commands, written out with one shell word per line below:

```
# command one: ssh
ssh \
  -A \
  1.1.1.1 \
  -C \
  "x=wrong; ssh -A 2.2.2.2. -C "x=right;

# command two: echo
echo \
  \$x""
```

---

#### Keeping the double quotes, how do I have it print `right`?

Backslash-escape the nested quotes so they don't close the quotes you intend to be outer.

```
ssh -A $HOST1 -C "x=wrong; ssh -A $HOST2 -C \"x=right; echo \$x\""
```

---

## Section 2: Best-Practice Alternatives

#### SSH - ProxyCommand

In practice, don't do this kind of explicit nested SSH invocation at all -- just use the `ProxyCommand` ssh config option:

```
ssh \
  -o "ProxyCommand ssh $HOST1 netcat -w 120 %h %p' \
  "$HOST2" 'x=right; echo "$x"'
```

---

#### Bash - nestable eval-safe quote generation

In general, trying to escape things by hand is much more error-prone than telling the shell to do it for you.

```
host2_cmd='x=right; echo "$x"'
printf -v host1_cmd '%q ' ssh -A "$HOST2" -C "$host2_cmd"
ssh "$HOST1" bash -s <<<"$host1_cmd"
```

To demonstrate, we could even do this with a third host in the way:

```
host3_cmd='x=right; echo "$x"'
printf -v host2_cmd '%q ' ssh -A "$HOST3" -C "$host3_cmd"
printf -v host1_cmd '%q ' ssh -A "$HOST2" -C "$host2_cmd"
ssh "$HOST1" bash -s <<<"$host1_cmd"
```

This works because in ksh and bash, `printf %q` quotes a string in such a way that it'll evaluate to its current contents when parsed by that same shell.